# Can I use Mass Effect 3's coalesced editor to make it think I've completed a certain mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've been having an issue with the Grissom Academy mission. It's a glitch, one that doesn't seem to have a chance in hell of getting fixed in the near future, and EA didn't seem interested in a problem that only a handful of people are experiencing. I suppose servers have to explode before they'll bat an eye.

Anyway, the glitch is causing me to not be able to complete the mission. I finished the game once (and was not happy with the results of not completing the Grissom mission), and am now doing a Part II runthrough in which I've used Gibbed's Save Editor to tweak some romance options, etc. Nothing big. I've also updated both my game and Origin to their respective latest updates (I'm on PC if you can't tell). I've worked my way back up to the Grissom mission and am still having the same fall-through-the-floor-after-Orion-cutscene problem. Very irritating. And before you ask, I've tried everything I can think of to fix the problem, including things suggested by others. I doubt there's a workaround; it's something that needs Bioware's attention, if only they'd actually pay attention.

So what I'd like to know is if I can use the handy coalesced editor that I've downloaded (Wenchy's version) to make my game think I've completed the mission. I realize I could totally exploit this and make ME think I've completed ALL the missions, but then what's the point in playing? I just want to make it think I've finished THIS mission, since Gibbed's editor doesn't let me edit which missions have been completed like it does for ME1 and ME2.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gibbed's editor is a savegame editor, the coalesced editor is for config files. As such, it is very likely unable to do the sort of alteration you want to do. You probably could make some edit to make a mission always count as completed, but it would likely only work for new games/games where you haven't already started that mission.